# d3 microlibraries not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, axis

I am just learning d3 but I can't understand why other microlibraries within d3 are not working after correctly loading d3. For example, if I do something like

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 20]).range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 20]).range([height, 0]);
```

My browser console says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined`, whereas I see this used in many examples. Similarly, something like

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");
```

would generate error about `svg` . I understand that once I do

```
<script src="d3-folder/d3.js"></script>
```

all the other smaller libraries should be available. Why is it not so on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a version problem of your included d3 file. Are you using D3 V3.x or V4.x?
In V3.x you are using a linaer scale like you posted:

```
d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 20]).range([0, width]);.
```

But in V4.x they changed the namespace to:

```
d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]).range([0, width]);
```

Axis are also separated in their different areas:

```
d3.axisTop - create a new top-oriented axis generator
d3.axisRight - create a new right-oriented axis generator
d3.axisBottom - create a new bottom-oriented axis generator
d3.axisLeft - create a new left-oriented axis generator
```

Here you can find the actual API reference for D3 V4.x: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using v4.x. Yeah scaleLinear() is working. How about d3.svg  and d3.axis? Any idear?

Comment: It looks like there are too many outdated tuts out there. That seems to be my undoing.